# How to convert string to function handle in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have to convert a string like `str='x^2+3'` into a function. A solution is to obtain an inline function, `f=inline(str)`, but it will be unsupported in future versions.

A workaround is `f=eval(['@(x)',f])` but it doesn't seem a neat option.

The function `str2func` doesn't work because it requires just the name of an existing function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doesn't the following work?

```
str = 'x^2+3';
f = str2func(['@(x)' str]);
```

Comment: As the OP claimed that `str2func` would not work, you could mention that with `['@(x)' str]` you actually create a function which is *existing* afterwards and convinces `str2func` to do its duty. Just a suggestion, I will delete the comment later on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll leave your comment in for now at least as it explains it well.

Comment: You could also say that `['@(x)' str]` is the "name" of anonymous function that is created on the fly

Comment: This method give an error in R2007a: `Warning: The input to STR2FUNC "@(x)x^2+3" is not a valid function name. This will generate an error in a future release.`,  I'll have to keep using `inline`. So no forward compatibility neither backwards compatibility.

Comment: Sorry, that my best (and only) shot. `eval` will probably still work, however much I dislike it...

Comment: This method does not give any warning in R2015b. Additionally, the latest documentation for `str2func` on the [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) specifies that it constructs a function handle from a "function name or a string that defines an anonymous function". The `@(x)` syntax defines an anonymous function in Matlab. It therefore seems that Matlab plans to continue supporting this method in the future. The same cannot be said for `inline`.